# Is it possible to transform terrain into glacier?

Tags: freeciv

In Freeciv, is it possible to transform land tiles into glacier? I have researched the "explosives" technology, which allows the building of engineer units. However, I don't see any options in an engineer's "Work" menu for transforming a tile into glacier. I want to transform some land tiles into glacier to prevent enemies from getting resources from those tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (and doing so would be a very inefficient way to deny resources).

You can transform a tile from a glacier to tundra but no tiles transform (or irrigate or mine) into glacier.

This image shows what happens to terrain when transformed.

[image: Teraforming chart]

Comment: What is a good way to deny resources? Transform tiles into swamp?

Comment: @Flux Transform city into ruins

Comment: Even at times when that is militarily possible, it could be politically infeasible. For example, it may be important to preserve a buffer state, but also weaken it by reducing its productive tiles.